# Replace all characters before and after specific characters

Tags: java, regex

I need to replace all characters in a string which come before an open parenthesis but come after an asterisk:

Input:
`1.2.3 (1.234*xY)`

Needed Output:
1.234

I tried the following:

```
string.replaceAll(".*\\(|\\*.*", "");
```

but I ran into an issue here where `Matcher.matches()` is `false` even though there are two matches... What is the most elegant way to solve this?

Comment: Perhaps like this `^[^(]*\(([^*]+)\*.*` and replace with group 1 https://regex101.com/r/ZpAjbD/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try matching the whole string, and replace with capture group 1

```
^[^(]*\(([^*]+)\*.*
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` start of string
- `[^(]*\(` Match any char except `(` and then match `(`
- `([^*]+)` Capture in group 1 matching any char except `*`
- `\*.*` Match an asterix and the rest of the line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ic8MEr/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/pjwQUV)

```
String string = "1.2.3 (1.234*xY)";
System.out.println(string.replaceFirst("^[^(]*\\(([^*]+)\\*.*", "$1"));
```

Output

```
1.234
```

Comment: I guess `replaceFirst` would be more suitable since there is only one replacement.

Comment: @anubhava You are completely right, I will update it in a min

Answer (score 3):

You may use this regex to match:

```bash
[^(]*\(|\*.*
```

and replace with an empty string.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pi04fN/1)

**RegEx Demo:**

- `[^(]*\(`: Match 0 or more characters that are not `(` followed by a `(`
- `|`: OR
- `\*.*`: Match `*` and everything after that

**Java Code:**

```bash
String s = "1.2.3 (1.234*xY)";
String r = s.replaceAll("[^(]*\\(|\\*.*", "");
//=> "1.234"
```

Comment: this only works in regex because the global flag is turned on. if you turn it off, you get the same issue as me. and as far as i understood, java does not have a global flag?

Comment: Java has `replaceAll` that doesn't need a global flag. I will add sample code as well.

Comment: i tried the string from your java code and the issue persists: it doesnt work on regexr when you turn off the global flag (which i dont know how to turn on in java?, help?)

Comment: But why regexr? You want this to work on Java code right? I have already shown you a working Java code that doesn't need any global flag.

Comment: thanks a lot for your time @anubhava. someone already provided a fitting solution.

Comment: The Java code works

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following regex:

```bash
^.*?\(([^*]*)\*\S+\)$
```

Here is the [Regex Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4C5cUB/1) and here is the [Java code Demo](https://ideone.com/lwWY9o) for used regex.

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for used Regex.

```bash
^       ##Matching starting of the value here.
.*?\(   ##Using lazy match here to match till ( here.
(       ##Creating one and only capturing group of this regex here.
  [^*]* ##Matching everything till * here.
)       ##Closing capturing group here.
\*      ##Matching * here.
\S+     ##Matching non-spaces 1 or more occurrences here.
\)$     ##Matching literal ) here at the end of the value.
```